# Is the free particle Gaussian wavepacket in the Schwartz space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

I have been reading that for a wave function to be in the [Schwartz function space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) (highly desirable for physical systems in the Rigged Hilbert Space (RHS) description of QM), among other criteria, it should be representable by a finite, or countably infinite, basis. For instance, a particle in a box, or a harmonic oscillator, can be represented by its countably infinite, orthogonal, energy eigenfunctions as its basis. Note, the wave function for a harmonic oscillator is often described by a Gaussian function, which is relevant to the following question.

A free particle (no potential energy or boundary conditions) can also be described by a Gaussian wave packet (which spreads in space over time). This wave packet is an integral over plane waves, each times a scaling factor which is a function of that plane wave's momentum. In that case, due to the above integral, there is a continuum infinity of energy eigenfunctions; they are not countably infinite. So, the energy eigenfunctions cannot form a countably infinite basis for that Gaussian wave packet. However, I think that the wave packet can still be in Schwartz space by representing it by a countably infinite number of orthogonal Hermite polynomials, which do occupy Schwartz space.

So, my question: is the free particle Gaussian wave packet (with a continuum of energy eigenvalues and eigenfunctions) in the Schwartz space, or in the "dual Schwartz space" of RHS?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can check it pretty easily from the definition.

Comment: @ Javier. Thank you. Do the Hermite polynomials, in fact, form an orthogonal countably infinite basis for the free particle Gaussian wave packet, and that is why you say yes?

Comment: Yes, they are, because they're the eigenstates of a self-adjoint operator, but you can just go to the definition of Schwartz space and verify that the Gaussian packet satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @javier The definition of Schwartz space does not explicetly require its functions to be expressible using a countably infinite basis. However, the Schwarz space is also used as a space that is isomorphic to the dense subspace that is a subset of the Hilbert space of the so-called Rigged Hilbert Space. That subspace requies the functions represented as vectors (or rays) in it to be expressible by a countably infinite orthogonal basis. So, in addition to the free particle wave packet satisfying Schwartz criteria, it also must have a countably infinite basis.

Comment: A vector can't have a basis, that's a property of the vector space. If you want to know if a specific function is in Schwartz space or not, you just check the definition. You're asking about a specific function, not the whole space.

Comment: @javier So, to paraphrase, the free particle Gaussian wave packet is in the Scheartz space and the Scheartz space has the Hermite polynomials as an orthogonal countably infinite basis?

Comment: @javier And when a wave function has countably infinite orthogonal energy eigenfunctions, those can be used as the basis for that wave function, too.